# SSIS import multiple excel files with error handling

Tags: error-handling, ssis, import-from-excel

I have task to import multiple excel files into sql server table, while iteration some excel files have header name changed or some times data type issue, due to which DFT fails and NO further iteration,  and package fails.

I want to log file names which got fail and want to continue loading excel file using  DFT  till the last excel file, and in the end I would like to have file names in one place which got fail, so that I could try again on them with some correction, can anybody help me out in this case?

Comment: I have placed DTF inside a Foreach loop with a dynamic excel source connection (Expression), Consider a 100 excel files in a folder, loop runs fine and insert into table upto 40th Excel file but suppose a error on 41st Excel due to column name differ (from others), now program fails , upto 40th Excel it is inserted, I have done this much till now, but what I want to implement Now is....  suppose there is an error on 41st, 48th,63rd Excel file, I want to log these eroneous files separatly

Comment: I want package to run for all proper excel from 1st to 100 and want to log eroneous excel files name separately in a text file. So that I could come to know that these 3 files have some error, later on I will correct that and re-run. Please assist.

Comment: Ok, but what have you done to research error handling in SSIS?  There are tons of articles on the internet explaining how to do it.